# Hyperparameter tuning of gradient boosting and neural network quantile regression

Tags: neural-networks, boosting, keras, hyperparameter, quantile-regression

I have am using Sklearns GradientBoostingRegressor for quantile regression as wells as a nonlinear neural network implemented in Keras.
I do however not know how to find the hyperparameters.

For the GradientBoostingRegressor a separate regression is fitted for each quantile. Do I find a new set of hyperparameters for every quantile or do I fit the same set of hyperparameters for every quantile?

And for Keras how do I decide on the hyperparameters as the way I have implemented the model, it predicts all quantiles at the same time. Below is an example of my implementation in Keras:

```
def quantile_loss_nn(y_true, y_pred):
    loss = 0
    for q_i, q in enumerate(quantiles):
        e = y_true - y_pred[:, q_i:q_i+1]
        loss += K.mean(K.maximum(q*e, (q-1)*e))
    return loss 

def nonlinear_M1(input_size, output_size, loss): 
    inputs = Input(shape=(input_size,))
    h = Dense(256, activation='relu')(inputs)
    h = Dense(256, activation='relu')(h)
    h = Dense(256, activation='relu')(h)
    h = Dense(256, activation='relu')(h)
    output = Dense(output_size)(h)
    model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=output)
    optimiser = RMSprop(lr=0.01, rho=0.9)
    model.compile(optimizer=optimiser, loss=loss, metrics=['mae'])
    return model

model_nonlinear_M1 = nonlinear_M1(X_train1.shape[1], len(quantiles), quantile_loss_nn)
epochs = 200
batch_size = 32
model_nonlinear_M1.fit(X_train1, y_train1,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=epochs,
          verbose=0)
```